# How to view images from diskette containing .IDC files from the late 1980s?

Tags: software, file-format

I had a friend send me five 3½-inch floppy disks containing .IDC files. The dates on these diskettes indicate they were taken in 1989. These diskettes are all structured the same, as they contain SLIDEDIR.IDC on each disk then start as IMG002.IDC to IMG010.IDC. The diskettes are labeled to contain photos and the structure in a hex editor seems to be structured as a photo but I cannot determine how to view these files or what they were captured on. I have stood up a SOS machine to start trying old programs. I have tried all the modern programs like XNview and others.

How do I view these image files?

Comment: I have my doubts you will find contemporary software which can open them. As suggested in one forum very old PaintShopPro may open them. But think about the files, 3.5" disk = 1.44MB/10=140kB, so the images are something like 500x300x8. You should consider if it deserve the effort.

Comment: If you get no joy here, then maybe https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/ could help.

Comment: Thanks for the responses!  I have tried the PaintShopPro with no luck unfortunately.

Comment: They appear to be [supported by XnView](https://www.xnview.com/en/image_formats/). Maybe the files or diskettes are corrupt? What are the symptoms with XnView?

Comment: A 500x300 picture is low resolution by today's standards, but can still convey useful and interesting information.  Plenty of the images we view on web pages are this size or even smaller.

Comment: They probably lack metadata about what produced them, and may be greyscale which would give more pixels per kb

Comment: Would you be willing to post a sample file? Probably not the SLIDEDIR.IDC (though that may be interesting) but one of IMG*.IDC

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search revealed an [IDC Converter](https://www.reaconverter.com/convert/idc.html), specifically made to batch convert IDC image files to more modern formats.

As noted, these will be low-res files (likely from a very early digital camera, or perhaps not even camera images; scanning printed photographs was still fairly new in 1989), but since you seem to have a diskette drive that can read the files, it may be worth investigating this conversion tool.

Comment: Check please here: https://www.photrio.com/forum/threads/diskette-containing-idc-files.203107/#post-2743746

Comment: Yea I have exhausted that option.  There was a thought that these could have been used as telephoto transmitter copies but can't verify that.